# Maximal irreducibility measure of positive Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

I am following "Markov Chains and Stochastic stability" by Meyn and Tweedie. Throughout the book they use the convention that $\psi$ refers to a maximal irreducibility measure, and call the corresponding chain $\psi$-irreducible.

When a $\psi$-irreducible chain admits an invariant probability measure $\pi$, which satisfies

\begin{equation}
\pi(A) = \int \pi(dx) P(x, A), \quad A \in \mathcal{B}
(\mathsf{X})
\end{equation}

they call the chain *positive*. My question is this: Will we, for positive chains, have $\psi = \pi$?

I think this intuitively would make sense (since any set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathsf{X})$ with $\pi(A) > 0$ should clearly be returned to in finite time with positive probability), but I am not able to find any explicit statements of such a property in the book. Is it because the statement false, beacuse it is trivial, or beause I have missed something?